# Playing a sound muting other applications

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm doing an interval timer app for Android phones to use while interval training.
At certain intervals I want to mute other applications (like the media player since I listen to music while training), play a custom sound (not any of the default notification sounds) and then unmute the other applications again. I would prefer if this mute/unmute was gradually so it won't be a drastic "cut" in music". I've been reading a bit and I can't decide if the best way to do this is through the "Ringtonemanager", "Notificationmanager" or simply play it through the media player?
I never done anything with sounds before so any help is much appreciated.
Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mute other applications by calling:

```
AudioManager am=context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int result=am.requestAudioFocus(listener,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                  AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSICVE);
```

result==AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED means that your application now has exclusive audiofocus and all other apps should be muted.

Comment: I play these sounds regularly in a thread/handler. Do I declare: `Audiomanager am`; in the onCreate of the class the thread belongs to? Do I have to release/destroy am after focus have been granted and I have played my sound effect?

Comment: You should create the AudioManager and request focus in the onCreate() method of your App. After you played your sound effect you should call am.abandonAudioFocus(listener) to unmute the other applications. You don't have to remove the AudioManager object, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mute other apps, you need to gain audio focus.[Managing Audio Focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html)